# Django Model formset is partially working

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I have normally just a simple question but I can't get it working.
I have a view where customers can add, delete or edit their addresses.

so the forms are generating, and I can open the edit_customer_form, the values are filled in because query set. But if I click on save, the form is posting, its hopping in the right loop: if 'edit_address' in request.POST: but I got the output from:         print('ERROR', edit_address_form.errors)

that all fields are required and there are no inputs given. That is strange.

The HTML forms looks like:

```
<input type="text" name="form-0-Address_Firstname" value="Christopher" class="form-control" autofocus="" id="id_form-0-Address_Firstname">
```

The error says:

```
ERROR [{'CustomerID': ['Dette felt er påkrævet.'], 'ID': ['Dette felt er påkrævet.']}, {'Address_Firstname': ['Dette felt er påkrævet.'],
```

In my eyes the field name is different to the value given by the prefix, which is necessary. But how can I save the form and give the values to the form.

view.py:

```
customer_addresses = CustomerAddresses.objects.filter(CustomerID=customer)
AddressFormSet = modelformset_factory(CustomerAddresses, form=CustomerAddressesForm, extra=0)
formset = AddressFormSet(queryset=customer_addresses, form_kwargs={'user': User.ID})
if request.method == 'POST':
    if 'add_address' in request.POST:
        add_address_form = CustomerAddressesForm(User.ID, request.POST)
        if add_address_form.is_valid():
            add_address_form.save()
    if 'edit_address' in request.POST:
        address_id = request.POST.get('id_Address')
        address_data = CustomerAddresses.objects.get(pk=address_id)
        edit_address_form = AddressFormSet(request.POST, queryset=customer_addresses, form_kwargs={'user': User.ID})
        print('ERROR', edit_address_form.errors)
        messages.error(request, 'ERROR')
        if edit_address_form.is_valid():
            instances = edit_address_form.save(commit=False)
            for instance in instances:
                instance.save()
        return redirect('addresses')
    if 'delete_customer_address_id' in request.POST:
        delete_customer_address_id = request.POST.get('delete_customer_address_id')
        request.session['delete_customer_address_id'] = delete_customer_address_id
        return redirect('delete-customer-address')
    if 'register_customer' in request.POST:
        register_form = CustomerAddressesForm(user=user_id)
        if register_form.is_valid():
            customer = register_form.save(commit=False)
            customer.UserID = user_id
            customer.save()
            # You can redirect to a success page or login the user directly
            redirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
else:
    add_address_form = CustomerAddressesForm(user=User.ID)
```

and my form:

```
class CustomerAddressesForm(forms.ModelForm):
    Title = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control mb-3', 'autofocus': True}),
                            required=False)
    Address_Firstname = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'autofocus': True}))
    Address_Lastname = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'autofocus': True}))
    Zip = forms.IntegerField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'maxlength': '5', 'data-toggle': 'maxlength'}),
        label='Postnummer')
    City = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'autofocus': True}))
    Address_Company = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'autofocus': True}),
                                      required=False)
    Street = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'autofocus': True}), required=False)
    Country = forms.ModelChoiceField(widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-select'}),
                                     queryset=CountryList.objects.values_list('countryname', flat=True).order_by(
                                         'code'), initial='Denmark', to_field_name='countryname')
    Is_Default_Shipping_address = forms.BooleanField(
        widget=forms.CheckboxInput(attrs={'class': 'form-check-input', 'id': 'customSwitch4'}), initial=False,
        required=False)
    Is_Default_Billing_address = forms.BooleanField(
        widget=forms.CheckboxInput(attrs={'class': 'form-check-input', 'id': 'customSwitch3'}), initial=False,
        required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = CustomerAddresses
        fields = ['Title', 'Address_Firstname', 'Address_Lastname', 'Zip', 'City', 'Address_Company', 'Country',
                  'Is_Default_Shipping_address', 'Is_Default_Billing_address', 'Address_CustomerSalutation',
                  'CustomerID', 'Street']

    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomerAddressesForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['Address_CustomerSalutation'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(
            widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-select mb-3'}),
            queryset=Salutation.objects.filter(UserID_id=user), empty_label=None)
```

Comment: Read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the the problem, it was a misunderstand, I created for every instance a own `<form>` tag, this was not working because

```
{{ formset.management_form }}
```

have to be in the form for all formsets.

I tried also

```
{{ form.instance.management_form }}
```

and

```
{{ form.management_form }}
```

in the `{% for form in formset %}` loop, but it was not working. I also excluded the CustomerID field because it will not be changed by the customer or the admin.